# Angular 2 Error: (SystemJS) Can't resolve all parameters for Component Service: (?)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I tried to call the web API from my Angular2 Component service in Visual Studio, but continuously I am getting the error like "(SystemJS) Can't resolve all parameters for anniversary service: (?)".

My sample application is working fine if I remove my component service.

ComponentService:

```
       import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
       import {Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
       import { IData } from '../Common/details';
       import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
       import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

       export class AniversaryService {
         constructor(private _http:Http) { }
         getImages(): Observable<IData[]> {
                return this._http.get("/api/ImageService/Details")
                .map((response: Response) => <IData[]>response.json()      
                };
        }
```

and my Corresponding Component:

```
        import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
        import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
        import { IData } from '../Common/details';
        import { AniversaryService } from './Aniversary.service';

        @Component({
        selector: 'my-AniversaryComponent',
        providers: [AniversaryService]
        })

        export class AniversaryComponent implements OnInit {
           data: IData[];
           constructor(private _aniversaryservice: AniversaryService) { }
           ngOnInit() {
           this._aniversaryservice.getImages().subscribe((details) => this.data 
           =details); 
           }
         }

        }
```

I tried different solutions from stack overflow but nothing works for me.

Please help me to overcome this problem.

Thanks in Advance for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The service appears to be missing the @Injectable decorator.